# Include vendor's tags for ruby-mode and ggtags

Tags: ruby-mode, ctags, gtags, enh-ruby-mode

I'm trying to install and configure the `ggtags` package. Primarily, I use it for a ruby on rails projects (`enh-ruby-mode`).

I can generate ctags including all vendor's files for my project with the following command:

```
ctags -R --languages=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths)
```

How can I configure `ggtags` package to achieve the same thing?

I use OS X, with installed `exuberant-ctags` and `pygments` plugins.

I think, I need to add some settings to `~/.globalrc` or to the project root's `gtags.conf`, but I don't know the settings.

Comment: I think you might just need to build `global` with `ctags` as its backend. With that `ctags` will go the parsing but `global` will save the database in its more efficient manner. Once you get that working from the terminal, `ggtags` package will also work the same way. With that, this might not be an emacs related question at all.

Comment: The question is how can I make `gtags` to run `ctags` with custom arguments? Can I configure it in `.globalrc`

Comment: I simply have a `~/.ctags` for ctags config and `~/.globalrc` for global config. You need to specify the ctags binary location when building global: http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Plug_002din

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use `global` installed from a Ubuntu repository. The version I've had in 6.6.3-2.

First, copy the example config to your home directory. A commentary at its top makes it seem like this is unnecessary, but that's not true. The default config it has is much different, and doesn't recognize `.rb` files at all, AFAICT.

```
cat /usr/share/doc/global/examples/gtags.conf.gz | gzip -d >~/.globalrc
```

Second, you need to choose the underlying mechanism. Pygments sounds great, but it generates "other symbol" entries, not definitions, which is what we normally need.

`universal-ctags` might be the best choice, but the version of Global seems to need recompiling to use it (either the apt or the snap version). `exuberant-ctags` works out of the box, though. The ancient version `5.9~svn20110310-1`.

Now, as explained in the documentation and in [this](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags/issues/185) issue, you would normally need to run `gtags --gtagslabel=` in every gem directory:

```
for d in $(bundle list --paths); do
    if [ -d $d ]; then
        echo "$d";
        (cd $d && find . -type f -name "*.rb" | gtags --gtagslabel=ctags -f -)
    fi
done
```

The use of `find` here is to avoid including JS files, etc, mostly because of the minified assets. But you can create a smarter enumeration.

To use the indexes from all these directories you need to set the env var `GTAGSLIBPATH` to the appropriate value during an Emacs session. Given that it's different for every project, and even changes over time, maybe the best approach is to manually call a command in the project directory that will do that for you. Here's one you can use:

```
(defun set-gtagslibpath-to-bundle-paths ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((paths
         (split-string
          (with-output-to-string
            (process-file-shell-command "bundle list --paths" nil
                                        standard-output))
          "\n")))
    (while (and paths
                (string-match-p "\\`The dependency'" (car paths)))
      (setq paths (cdr paths)))
    (setenv "GTAGSLIBPATH"
            (mapconcat #'identity paths ":"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate the tags with the following command to command to be read by ggtags

```
gtags --gtagslabel=ctags
```

The above command should be helpful of any language not supported by gtags but supported by ctags.

Comment: What if it doesn't work? Does gtags need to be compiled in a particular way to benefit from ctags?