# How do you get gtags working with Lua?

Tags: ctags, gtags, tags

How do you get gtags working with Lua?
I want to be able to have same tags functionality for Lua like with C/C++, i.e. find definitions of functions, function references, symbol references, etc.
I have universal ctags and gtags on my system and tried the `ctags` and `new-ctags` options when doing `ggtags-create-tags`, but when I try using ggtags functions nothing happens on Lua functions & variables.

Comment: My answer here might help you: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54620/124

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the tags running `gtags --gtagslabel=ctags` from the root of the project, using a configuration from ubuntu (`zcat /usr/share/doc/global/examples/gtags.conf.gz > ~/.globalrc`).
It included at least C, C++, Lua and Javascript.